# C Disable command-line input

Tags: c, command-line, stdin, ncurses, appkit

I'm creating a ncurses program which reads system-wide keystrokes using AppKit. To clear the wall of text that accumulates on the command line while I run the program I execute this line of code before exiting the program.

```
while((c = getch()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}
```

My question is if there is a more efficient way to solve this. For example disabling command line input while the program executes.

Edit:

I ran some tests and my problem seems to be rooted in usleep and not ncurses or AppKit. Here is an example:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    usleep(5000000);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Input in the terminal while your program is running should be discarded when the program exits. There should be no need for you to explicitly do it.

Comment: For me this is the command line when I exit(0) the program:

    bash-4.4$ ddddddaaaaaaaaaaawwwwwwwwwwdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaax

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. It is not clear what you want to accomplish. Provide a [mcve] with the details.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That's not true if the input isn't buffered by the program. Since he's using `ncurses`, the terminal is in raw mode and it only reads from the terminal when the program calls an input function, with no buffering.

Comment: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/ncurses-c-how-to-clear-stdin-buffer-4175447149/ shows a solution similar to the one in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Try `tcflush(STDIN_FILENO, TCIFLUSH)` before `exit()`.

---

According to `tcflush(3)`:

> `int tcflush(int fd, int queue_selector);`
>
> `tcflush()` discards data written to the object referred to by `fd` but not transmitted, or data received but not read, depending on the value of `queue_selector`:
>
> `TCIFLUSH :` flushes data received but not read.
>   `TCOFLUSH :` flushes data written but not transmitted.
>   `TCIOFLUSH:` flushes both data received but not read, and data written but not transmitted.

Comment: Thanks, it works but I wonder if this feature could be disabled altogether.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Your application can easily ignore the input so the terminal driver need not provide such functionality since it cannot really stop the user from typing from the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

curses provides a function for this, called [`flushinp`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_util.3x.html#h3-flushinp):

> The  **`flushinp`**  routine  throws away any typeahead that has
>   been typed by the user and has not yet been  read  by  the
>   program.

Your two program fragments do not show this, but the ncurses manual page's section on [initialization](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-Initialization) suggests that you turn off echo (by curses) initially:

```
initscr(); cbreak(); noecho();
```

Whether you do that or not, curses actually puts the terminal into *raw mode* and chooses whether to echo characters typed while your program is running in curses mode.

The first fragment, using `getch` is a curses function.  ncurses attempts to read all input characters into its own buffer, and processes them at the rate your program needs.  The `flushinp` call tells it to discard that buffered input.  By the way, your code should use **`ERR`** for the check rather than **`EOF`**, although for most implementations of curses those are the same numeric value.

When your program stops curses mode (using `endwin`), it puts the terminal back to the modes where it was initially, i.e., echoing buffered input.

The other fragment of code is not a curses application.  The terminal stays in *cooked mode* (echoing, buffered), and that accumulates in the terminal driver, unread by your program.  On exit from the program, the next program (or your shell) gets a chance to read that.

As suggested (rather implied) if your program is not running in curses mode when it exits, you could use the [POSIX termios call](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tcflush.html) **`tcflush`** to discard the input pending on the terminal, which is what ncurses does (see [source](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/master/ncurses/tinfo/lib_kernel.c#L151)).